# Error when trying to use UNION ALL syntax on SAP HANA

Tags: hana

I have a problem when trying to combine 2 syntax with UNION ALL on SAP HANA. It says:

> SAP DBTech JDBC: [339]: invalid number:  [6930] attribute value is not a number; attribute value is not a number

I tried searching everywhere on Google, but I couldn't find a solution for this problem.

Comment: Please post the failing query and the column definitions of the projected columns.

Comment: You will not find the solution for this on Google or anywhere else, because the DBMS tells you the exact problem: some of your columns have different datatypes in different parts of `UNION ALL`, and some column of some row cannot be (implicitly) converted to number (due to the value is not numeric at all or its datatype doesn't conform implicit [conversion matrix](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/46ff9650c7f44461a6146269c1e2a4c6.html))

Comment: so how can i solve this problem?

Comment: By examining the datatypes of both parts of `UNION` on the same position. To do this, issue `create table ... as (select * from <part_of_union>)` and compare two tables: they should have the same datatypes on the same positions.